# Update query in mongodb not working

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a document that stores detail of employees. This is my document structure.

```
{
    "emp_id" : 1,
    "Employee_Name" : "Fareed Khan Jan",
    "Employee_Contact" : "07492897789",
    "Employee_Gender" : "Male",
    "Employee_Address" : "Lewisham",
    "IS_Available" : "YES",
    "Employee_Reports" : [ 
        {
     "Report_Title" : "Initial Project Design",
     "Report_Details" : "This is a sample report.",
     "Date_Submit" : "26/10/2015"
        }
    ],
    "Employee_Salary" : [ 
        {
            "month_year" : "Jan-2015",
            "actual_salary" : 200.0000000000000000,
            "bonus" : 0.0000000000000000,
            "penalty" : 0.0000000000000000,
            "bonus_pen_detail" : "NA",
            "total_amount_paid" : 200.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "month_year" : "Feb-2015",
            "actual_salary" : 200.0000000000000000,
            "bonus" : 0.0000000000000000,
            "penalty" : 0.0000000000000000,
            "bonus_pen_detail" : "NA",
            "total_amount_paid" : 200.0000000000000000
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to update the embedded document 'Employee_Salary' where "month-year" is 'Feb-2015'. I have written the following query but it deletes all the data inside 'Employee_Salary' and update the one. I don't want to delete other data inside this.

```
db.employees.update
(
      { 'emp_id': 1, 'Employee_Salary.month_year' : "Feb-2015" }, 
      { '$set': { 
        'Employee_Salary': [
            {
            "month_year" : "Feb-2015",
            "actual_salary" : 200.0000000000000000,
            "bonus" : 80.0000000000000000,
            "penalty" : 0.0000000000000000,
            "bonus_pen_detail" : "NA",
            "total_amount_paid" : 280.0000000000000000 
            }
            ]
    }}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you tell it to `$set` Employee_Salary with the new array.

To modify the one you looked for in your find, you have to use the [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) operator:

```
{ '$set': { 
        "Employee_Salary.$.bonus" : "80.0000000000000000"
}}
```